# moving mouse in Unity Cardboard VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouse, virtual-reality

I want to move camera in Cardboard VR environment by pushing mouse, but I cannot figure out how to make it work. Any Ideas?

Below is a simple code piece to move camera.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cam;
    protected Vector3 left;
    protected Vector3 forward;
    public float scalemove;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        left = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
        forward = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        left = left * scalemove;
        forward = forward * scalemove;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0)
        {
            cam.Translate(left * Time.deltaTime);
            //Code for action on mouse moving left
            print("Mouse moved left");
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") > 0)
        {
            cam.Translate(-left * Time.deltaTime);
            //Code for action on mouse moving right
            print("Mouse moved right");
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") < 0)
        {
            cam.Translate(-forward * Time.deltaTime);
            //Code for action on mouse moving left
            print("Mouse moved down");
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") > 0)
        {
            cam.Translate(forward * Time.deltaTime);
            //Code for action on mouse moving right
            print("Mouse moved up");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Unity2019 on Windows10.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

just give the camera an empty parent, use the mouse to change the position of the parent, and the code runs OK. Best!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).